# Error while trying to connect PostgreSQL to the database?

Tags: postgresql, create-table

I tried connecting my Postgres database `Employees` to a SQL Server, however, whenever I try, I get an error saying the request was ignored.

[Trying to create database on sql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I04kN.png)

I tried to create a new database called employees with template0 on SQL Server from postgres after initializing the postgres on SQL Server by typing in

```
~psql -U postgres
```

and I get an error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMClU.png)

Comment: 'SQL Server' is the name of a product from Microsoft. Does your question have anything to do with that product?

Comment: You aren't actually running `psql` here - you are typing the command into a prompt that is asking you about a hostname. Also, please don't post tiny little pictures of text - just copy+paste the text.

Comment: 1) You are working with Postgres not SQL Server, so remove the `sql-server` tag. 2) You are working with the `psql` shell command from a `pgAdmin4` install. 3) You need to follow the prompts and supply the `Server`(host name), `Database`(name), `Port`(number) and `Username` values in order. You can enter the [default] values by just hitting the Enter key. Then you will be in the `psql` program where you can rune the `CREATE DATABASE`.

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot you provided you are writing queries in the fields of host, post and username that's why you get an error because you are writing queries before even connecting to the database.

You should follow the prompts and enter the required information like hostname, port and username If you want to use the default values (which is between brackets) hit enter.

After connecting to the database you can now write your queries.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it provided me with the clarity.

Comment: Hi All, When i am trying to enter the default values saying ~psql -U <postgres> <Employees> to connect the database to the sql server so i can run the command to create the database and hitting enter, the entire psql program window is getting closed automatically. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore all the warnings, the important part is that it cannot find the host from Your shell, check the command syntax.

https://hasura.io/blog/top-psql-commands-and-flags-you-need-to-know-postgresql/

So this command you display is only part of what you need

```
psql -d <db-name> -U <username> -W
```

apparently the default will be this implementation if you do not specify anyting, like in your case:

```
psql -h <host-address> -d <db-name> -U <username> -W
```

so then it interprets your "-U" as the host which cannot be found,
so try using explicit arguments and if your database is on your local host, you can ignore the host argument

Comment: I am going to try running the code once again with the help of your suggestion, and will get back to you soon. Thanks for the info, Nielsen.

Comment: any luck with any of that @SushmitaGhosh ? did You locate the problem?

Comment: the problem got sorted, no worries